# pushing and poping into new list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, stack

I am trying to make a loop that if the program sees a `letter` or `number` it will push(x) into a new list and if it sees an asterisk * it must pop(). It is more of a stack algorithm where the first letter or number in is the last one out. FILO First in last out

For example

If the program is given the following array

```
inputVals = ["1", "2" ,"*" ,"3", "4", "*" ,"*", "*" ,"5", "6"]
```

It should output

```
outputVal = ["2" ,"4", "3" ,"1"]
```

or a letter input

```
inputLetter = ["f" ,"a", "*", "d" ,"e" ,"t" ,"*" ,"o", "*" ,"*" ,"*" ,"*"]
```

letter Output

```
outPutLetter = ["a" ,"t", "o", "e" ,"d" ,"f"]
```

How can I implement this?

Comment: The order outputVal is not clear to me.

Comment: @MehdiMostafavi It is because of the popping sequence that the `outputVal` turns out like that

Comment: @roganjosh No its supposed to be `["2" ,"4", "3" ,"1"]` i think the sequence of pushing into a new array and popping the asterisk causes it to be like this. That is why I am struggling to make the algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
def foo(input_list):
    result = []
    stack = []
    for i in input_list:
        if i == "*":
            result.append(stack.pop())
        else:
            stack.append(i)
    return result

print(foo(["1", "2" ,"*" ,"3", "4", "*" ,"*", "*" ,"5", "6"]))
print(foo(["f" ,"a", "*", "d" ,"e" ,"t" ,"*" ,"o", "*" ,"*" ,"*" ,"*"]))
```

```
['2', '4', '3', '1']
['a', 't', 'o', 'e', 'd', 'f']
```

Comment: Thank you sooo soo much for this answer . What would be the modification to this to implement `First in First Out ` using the same idea . I am trying to understand making such algorithms and wanted some insight. Thank you again

Comment: You can change `stack.pop()` to `stack.pop(0)` to make it FIFO. Or `stack.append(i)` to `stack.insert(0, i)`. Both have the same time complexity, O(N).

Comment: If you want an O(1) time complexity with FIFO, you should probably implement your own data structure or import external libraries.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be this:

```
def asteriks_popping(list_in):
    result_list = []
    tmp_list = []
    for item in list_in:
        if item == '*':
            result_list.append(tmp_list.pop())
        else:
            tmp_list.append(item)

    return result_list
```